# API Gateway cors issue from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I'm really stuck here and none of the cors related solutions I've found have helped so this is my last resort.

I have created an API Gateway with a POST method that triggers a Lambda function, which adds an item to a DynamoDB table.

Everything works perfectly when I try the POST method in API Gateway but if I try to make an AJAX call from a website hosted on my s3 bucket I get this cors error:

**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I've enabled cors on the API Gateway and I've added basically all cors Access-Controll-Allow-etc that I can find to the JavaScript that performs the AJAX call but nothing works. I'm still getting the same error...

Would really appreciate any help possible since I'm just debugging in circles now.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is confusing. Have you a problem with the CORS on your API Gateway or on your S3 bucket ? Precise your question, to have a correct response.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remember to deploy the API again after enabling CORS in the console.
(Silly me forgot that and was running in circles. )

On another note, one good way to help debugging is to curl the API gateway url to see if the CORS header exists in the API gateway's response(`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`). If not, then you know API gateway didn't enable CORS properly.

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2020 13:20:18 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 215
< Connection: keep-alive
< x-amzn-RequestId: 1f786173-23f7-412e-a106-64105235b253
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *      //See if this is missing
< x-amz-apigw-id: QOyu2E15tjMFoGQ=
< X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-5f1c3192-8b2f67e02bcb71ce1e0bb254;Sampled=0
<
{"statusCode":200,"body":{"key":"value"}}* Connection #0 to host 1111.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com left intact
```

Inspired by this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-test-cors.html

Comment: thank you so much! this was my problem haha all I had to do was to redeploy and now it works

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to access a S3 bucket from your s3 hosted site** you'll need to add CORS rules in the S3 Bucket as per docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html).

The rules will be something like this -- the `<AllowedOrigin>` will be your site url

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>http://www.example1.com</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

**If you want to access your API from a s3 hosted site** you can either

- Configure CORS in API gateway according to docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)

or

- Return CORS headers for `OPTIONS` requests from your Lambda function/application code. For example in AspNet, it can be simply done by adding [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1) which does that for you.